# Proving which ideals of $K[x,y]$ are primes or maximals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K$ be a field. Which of these ideals of $K[x,y]$ are primes? And maximals? $$I_1=(x+y,y-3), I_2=(x^2+y)$$
I know what is a prime ideal, a maximal ideal and a field, and I still can't see how to solve this problem. These are just 2 of a large list of ideals, I would appreciate if someone could solve it so I can use these as an example to solve the others.

Comment: $(x+y,y-3) = (x+3,y-3)$

Comment: One of the corollaries of the Hilbert Nullstellensatz will tell you what the maximal ideals are in the case that $K$ is algebraically complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try to figure out what the rings $K[x,y]/I_1$ and $K[x,y]/I_2$ are. If it's a domain, then you have a prime idea. If it's a field, then you have a maximal ideal.

For example, in $K[x,y]/I_1$ we will have $x\equiv -y$ and $y\equiv 3$, which means that $K[x,y]/I_1\simeq K$, which is a field. In $K[x,y]/I_2$ we have $y\equiv -x^2$, which means that $f(x,y)\in K[x,y]$ is congruent to $f(x,-x^2)$ in $K[x,y]/I_2$. You should then be able to convince yourself that $K[x,y]/I_2\simeq K[x]$, which is a domain.

Comment: I've proved in the past that if the ring $K[x,y]/I$ it's a domain, then it's a prime ideal, and if it's a field, then I have a maximal ideal, so I understand the argument. However I don't see why having $x\equiv -y$ and $y\equiv 3$, means that $K[x,y]/I_1\simeq K$, is a field. I have tried to construct a morphism and using the first isomorphism theorem without succeeding. I think it is because I've never worked with a $K[x,y]$ with 2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have $I_1 = (x+3,y-3)$, can you see how $K[x,y]/I_1 \cong K$ and conclude that $I_1$ is maximal and hence a prime?

For the second one you have $K[x,y]/I_2 \cong K[x]$. This follows, as you have $y \equiv -x^2 \pmod {I_2}$. Hence we have that $I_2$ is prime, but not maximal, as $K[x]$ is an integral domain, but not a field.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $K[x,y]/I_2$ is isomorphic to $K$?

Comment: @JohnKeeper As written in the answer it's isomorphic to $K[x]$, not $K$.

Answer (score 0):

$K[x,y]/(x+y,y-3)\cong K[x]/ (x+3)\cong K$, so $I_1$ is a maximal ideal, because $K$ is a field.

$K[x,y]/(x^2+y)\cong K[x,-x^2]\cong K[x]$, so $I_2$ is a prime ideal, because $K[x]$ is a domain integral. .